# PASSAR DADO DE UMA TELA PARA OUTRA SEM NAVIGATOR NO FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

BOM DIA!!
Estou fazendo um app e neste em uma unica tela existe uma lista com opções ( o widget de opção no caso é listoption ) e uma outra area que mostra qual o listoption foi selecionado.

basicamente estou querendo passar o valor da variável nome de um widget para outro, mas sem que abra uma nova tela.

Deste quero que onPressed passe o nome da opção selecionada:

```
class ListOption extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListOption({super.key, required this.nome});

  final String nome;

 

  @override
  State<ListOption> createState() => _ListOptionState();
}

class _ListOptionState extends State<ListOption> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        width: 70,
        height: 70,
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
           
          },
          child: Text(widget.nome),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Para este, quero exibir onde atualmente está como widget.nome selecionado:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  MyInfo({super.key, this.nomeselecionado});
  
  String? nomeselecionado;
  

  @override
  State<MyInfo> createState() => _MyInfoState();
}

class _MyInfoState extends State<MyInfo> {
    bool isSwitched = false;
    String? selectedOption  ;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return //TESTE DE BOTAO TBM
        Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7 * 0.25,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 20,
                  width: 300,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    color: Color.fromARGB(153, 180, 177, 177),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    "CONFIGURAÇÂO ATUAL",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Container(
                        //esse container que vai aparecer o nome
                        width: 70,
                        height: 60,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                         child: Center(
                          child: Text(widget.nomeselecionado ?? ""),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Switch(
                      value: isSwitched,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          isSwitched = value;
                          print(isSwitched);
                        });
                      },
                      activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                      activeColor: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

mas todos exemplos que vi usam o navigator e abre outra tela e nao quero isso.

pois esses dois widgets ficam em uma mesma tela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver isso existem algumas formas diferentes. A mais simples é:

Dentro do widget `ListOption` crie um argumento de callback. Esse argumento deve ser uma função que vai ser chamada no `onPressed`:

```dart
class ListOption extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListOption({super.key, required this.nome, required this.callback});
  final String nome;
  final Function callback; // Nova variável criada.
  @override
  State<ListOption> createState() => _ListOptionState();
}
```

Usando essa variável, chame ela diretamente no parâmetro `onPressed`:

```dart
child: TextButton(
          onPressed: (){
            widget.callback("Valor a ser passado"); // Chamada do callback.
          },
          child: Text(widget.nome),
        ),
```

Ao criar esse widget, você agora deve passar também o novo parâmetro que você criou. É uma função e portanto a estrutura é parecida com o que você fez no `onPressed`. Isto é, na tela que engloba os dois widgets, você vai usar algo do tipo:

```dart
ListOption(nome: "", callback: (String valorRecebido){
    setState((){
        stringASerMostradaNoSegundoWidget = valorRecebido;
    });
})
```

Vale deixar claro que nesta tela que engloba os dois widgets você vai precisar de uma nova variável para armazenar essa informação:

```dart
String stringASerMostradaNoSegundoWidget = '';
```

Para este callback, use o `setState` [para atualizar o estado](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) dos widgets nessa tela.

Feito isso, é necessário que o widget que use esta informação, `MyInfo` receba essa mesma variável que o callback acabou de atribuir. Ao chamá-lo, você deve usar algo da forma:

```dart
[...]
MyInfo(nomeselecionado: stringASerMostradaNoSegundoWidget);
[...]
```

E com essas alterações você já deve ter o resultado desejado.

---

O nome disso é *gerenciamento de estado* e é um tópico bem extenso e para horas de discussão. Estado é o nome que se dá a essas variáveis que você usa para construir sua tela, como usamos ali.

No seu caso, era uma tela simples que só precisava passar um texto de um widget para o outro. Porém conforme o aplicativo cresce, esse tipo de abordagem acaba não sendo tão simples. Fazer isso em uma escala grande é impraticável.

Podem ter múltiplos widgets que precisam de múltiplas variáveis de estado com ações que alterem o estado de outros widgets na árvore. Nesses casos, é recomendado utilizar um gerenciamento de estados mais elaborado, e diversas alternativas podem ser encontradas na [documentação oficial da Google](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) (em inglês). Nessa mesma página tem também um [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro) para uma introdução ao assunto, com um exemplo que pode ser interessante olhar depois.